# Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma for Spherical Harmonics expansion

Tags: differential-geometry, fourier-analysis, spherical-harmonics

Here is my question:
A basic result of classical Fourier analysis is that the fourier coefficients of an $L^1$ function must tend to zero (Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma). Is there analogous result to the spherical harmonic expansions? And how can we prove it ?

It will be great if someone can help me here or/and can also provide few good references for the same.

ps: 1) I also found this question in a text book: `[Geometric Analysis of the Bergman Kernel and Metric][1]`from where I reformulated my question.

2) I am not a mathematician so please bear my naive comments in discussions.

Comment: Do you treat them as functions on the spheres?

Comment: Hi John, I didn't understand your question. You are referring to what when you say "them" ?

Comment: So are you working on $\mathbb S^n$ and the spherical harmonic functions are considered functions on $\mathbb S^n$?

Comment: I am working on $\mathbb{S}^2$ to be more precise, and I am studying expansion of functions $\in \mathbb{S}^2$.

Comment: In $L^2$, at least, the fourier coefficients must decay to zero at infinity because the $L^2$ norm of a function is the sum of the squares of its fourier coefficients.

Comment: @Neal, this is true but, is it also true in the case of spherical harmonic (expansion) coefficients? If you have a good reference for it I will be happy to check out.

Comment: The spherical harmonic expansion is the fourier expansion on the round sphere. Spherical harmonics : sphere :: sines and cosine : circle.

Comment: This is because on a closed Riemannian manifold, eigenfunctions of the Laplace operaror form an orthonormal basis of $L^2$.

Comment: @Neal I have read the same. However, if you can point out a reference or can help me in deriving riemann-lebesgue lemma for SH expansion I think it can help me more.

Comment: @sinbag: The proof for the special case of sphere can be found in "Rimeannian geometry" by Gallot, Hulin and Lafontaine in p.228. More information can be found in chapter 4 of that book, but unforunately the proof is not given there. (Actually a proof for general $M$ is a bit involved, using a lot of PDE)

Comment: Thanks @John. I have looked into the book and it looks pretty intricate to me. I will see if it can help me. Thanks again!